# Eclipse 2.5 spec web app error

Tags: java, eclipse

Have a running 2.5 web module project on my eclipse. I wanted to upgrade to Java 8 (currently running 7). When I set the compiler compliance of the project to Java 8, I'm getting error icon on the project. And the unsupported version exception when loading the class in tomcat (8)

Answer (score 1):

Setting compiler compliance of a project to Java 8 is not enough. You need to:

- Add a Java 8 "Installed JRE" in the "Preferences".
- Change the "JRE System Library" of the project to use the new JRE.
- Change compiler compliance of the project.

To run the code, you also need to:

- Change Tomcat to use a Java 8 runtime.

If Tomcat is running as a Windows Service, you need to remove and re-add the service, because it remembers the Java version that was in effect when it was added.

Comment: Thanks I did that. The problem was in eclipse tomcat server project's config. Even after changing the jre under bootstrap entries to java 8 and applying changes, it didn't get committed. removed server the project and created it again and the changes got reflected